# Making Windows Talk

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, text-to-speech, speech-to-text

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OS X `say` command for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/223913/os-x-say-command-for-windows)

When I switched to Mac OS X from a PC for work purposes, I found an interesting perk: it's easy to make the computer "speak" to you via Terminal. However I recently got a PC laptop, and am wondering if there is a similar command to the `say` command from OS X present in Windows XP that takes somewhat similar (if not exactly the same) parameters. Is there such a thing? If not an individual command, a batch file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Windows XP includes Text-To-Speech as an accessibility option. You can see how to configure it [in this knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306902).

There isn't a native command that does it from the command line, but someone wrote up something to do that called [say.exe](http://krolik.net/post/Say-exe-a-simple-command-line-text-to-speech-program-for-Windows.aspx).